# Chrome extension passing message to background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to build a Google Chrome extension which can send a message to background page from content script and display alert according to the sent message.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "fb_rainbow",
  "description": "Change Facebook Themes Colors",
  "version": "1.1",
  "background": {
  "page":"background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "popup":"popup.html"
    },
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus",
    "background"
],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
"web_accessible_resources":["injectin.js"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.facebook.com/*"],
      "js": ["color_change.js"]
    }
  ]
```

color_change.js (works and can get the alert)

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage( {message:'execute'} , function() { alert('message sent!'); });
```

background.html

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
if(request.message=="execute"){
    alert("message received!");
}else if{
    alert("message not received!");
}
});
```

But i don't receive any alerts from the background page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problems in your code

```
if(request.message=="execute"){
    alert("message received!");
}else if{
    alert("message not received!");
}
```

there is no `else if{` in java script use `else {`.

## Working Version

#### background.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

#### background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
if(request.message=="execute"){
    alert("message received!");
}else{
    alert("message not received!");
}
});
```

Comment: "background" **is** a valid permissions in manifest section. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html#bg .

Answer (score 0):

There is ***else if*** in js, but it should be ***else if()***. So you omitted the ***else if()***.
In your case, ***else*** is enough.